# Instagram API Pulling Images Without Authorization Page

Tags: web-services, api, instagram

So I was going through Instagram's API and I implemented it. However it isn't as useful as I thought it would be because when trying to get and OAuth2 token a user is taken to a page to authorize them in what looks to be and effort of insuring that the user realizes that they are about to view and share Instagram content with my application. This all makes sense to me although not ideal. You can find it in detail [here(Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL)](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Then I saw [this press release](http://celtra.cmail2.com/t/ViewEmail/j/B154DB5D55FDEE21/B28207D49A3AD10B9A8E73400EDACAB4) from a company called Celtra who says they can pull the the most recent images off any Instagram feed and put them in an Ad. I checked it out and somehow they are pulling the images of other companies without this authorization page I am encountering. Basically without page scrapping I don't know how to do this with Instagrams API, and I realize scraping violates Instagrams terms of service.  Does anyone have this functionality, where I can pull down images from Instagram and not take a user to an authentication page working legally as I am assuming Celtra is doing? Guidance or documentation on how to achieve this would be ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instagram recently added an [endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_with_client_id) that will allow you to any instagram account's photos without oauth or needing access_token, you can specify client_id and make API call to get photos.

Just register for an app account at [here](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) and add the client_id to this endpoint and make call:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

You only need access_token to get users' likes, follower feed and to like/comment/follow.

> update: you need to have `access_token` with the new API changes, cannot
>   access API with just `client_id` anymore

Comment: Doesn't work any more:

    {"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}

Comment: u need to have `access_token` now with the new API changes, cannot access API with just `client_id`

Answer (score 0):

To do this simply, you could authenticate your app from a dummy profile or your own personal profile and then use the access_token to request the feeds of any account. Then, when an end user goes to use your product, instead of authenticating them, you can just pull content from the Instagram API using your access_token.

Comment: Do you think this is legal. I mean it would work but seems like I'm violating their terms of service?

Comment: the other answer is a better way to do this, and is not violating terms of service (nor is my method, but it is a less straightforward way)